# Errors in computing the Euclidian distance between point and convex polytope using cvxpy

Tags: python, euclidean-distance, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I am trying to find the euclidian distance between a d-dimensional polytope defined as `A x <= b` and a point, called `point` in the code below, that I am certain is outside of the polytope. This is a convex quadratic minimization problem. I would like to use `cvxpy` for this purpose since I have this dependency for the project anyways. Below, I have a 2 dimensional polytope (the third dimension is actually constant) and a point, and the output of `cvxpy` confuses me greatly.

**Questions**:
why is the minimum found by cvxpy smaller than the manually computed 2-norm?
We can clearly see that the point found by `cvxpy` is not the one that minimizes the Euclidian distance to the polytope, why is this?
If this is the wrong approach for finding the minimum distance, how should I instead go about it?

NB `pypoman` is a package for finding the vertices of the polytope, which is convenient for plotting.

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp
import pypoman
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull, convex_hull_plot_2d

A = np.array([
    [ 0.,  0., -1.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
    [ 0., -1.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0., -1.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
    [ 0.,  3., -1.],
    [ 0., -3.,  1.],
    [-1.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 1.,  0., -1.],
    [-1.,  0.,  1.],
    [-1.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 1.,  3., -1.],
    [-1., -3.,  1.]
])
b = np.array([-10.,  10.,   0.,   2.,   0., 100.,   0., 100.,   0., 100.,   0., 100.,   0., 100.,   0., 100.])

vertices = pypoman.duality.compute_polytope_vertices(A, b)
vertices = np.array(vertices)

x_cp = cp.Variable(A.shape[1])
constraints = [
    A @ x_cp <= b,
]
point = cp.Constant([8.0, 2.0, 10.0])
objective = cp.Minimize(cp.norm(x_cp - point, 2))
problem = cp.Problem(objective=objective, constraints=constraints)

print(f'cvxpy minimum: {problem.solve()}')
print(f'point coordinates: {x_cp.value}, CLEARLY NOT THE CLOSEST POINT!')
print(f'distance: {sum((point.value - x_cp.value)**2)}, DIFFERENT FROM CVXPY MINIMUM???')

hull = ConvexHull(vertices[:, :2])
_ = convex_hull_plot_2d(hull)
plt.scatter(*x_cp.value[:2], c='r', label='cvxpy closest')
plt.scatter(*point.value[:2], c='g', label='point')
plt.legend(loc=3, framealpha=1.0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like the point is is in 3D? Your plot is in 2D?